# Spark unevenly distributes load

Tags: java, apache-spark

No matter how much resource I put to the system it cannot go below 11 min.

[image]

I am trying to parallelize a simple Spark program processes HBase data in parallel.

```
// Get Hbase RDD
JavaPairRDD<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result> hBaseRDD =
  jsc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
    conf,
    TableInputFormat.class,
    ImmutableBytesWritable.class,
    Result.class
  );

long count = hBaseRDD.count();
```

[image]

The problem is my program is as slow as the largest bar.

Found that ZK is taking long time before shutting.

```
18/05/19 17:26:55 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server <IP>:2181, sessionid = 0x163662b64eb046d, negotiated timeout = 40000
18/05/19 17:38:00 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x163662b64eb046d closed
```